# How to compare current active tab's URLs

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Trying to code an adblocker for a specific website.

I already have the code which deletes the ads on the homepage, but it still works on, for example: Movie pages. And that causes info section, with poster and everything, to be deleted. So, I only want this specific piece of code to run on Homepage. which can be https://net.adjara.com/ or https://net.adjara.com/Home. This website is an AJAX one, it's loaded once and that's it.

This is the code which deletes the ads on the homepage :

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.message === 'Homepage') {

    var timer = setInterval(deletor, 1);

    function deletor() {
        timer;
        var slider = document.querySelector("#slider-con");
        var bannerTop = document.querySelector("#MainContent > div:nth-child(2)")
        var bannerMiddle = document.querySelector("#MainContent > iframe");
        var bannerRandom = document.querySelector("#MainContent > div:nth-child(3)");


            if (slider) {
                slider.parentNode.removeChild(slider);
            }

            if (bannerTop) {
                bannerTop.parentNode.removeChild(bannerTop);
            }

            if (bannerMiddle) {
                bannerMiddle.parentNode.removeChild(bannerMiddle);
            }

            if (bannerRandom) {
                bannerRandom.parentNode.removeChild(bannerRandom);
            }
};
    } else {
        return false;
    }
})
```

This is the bg script which sends the message:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function
  (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    // read changeInfo data and do something with it (like read the url)
    if (changeInfo.url == "net.adjara.com" || "net.adjara.com/Home" || "net.adjara.com/Home/") {
      chrome.tabs.sendMessage( tabId, {
        message: "Homepage",
        url: changeInfo.url
      })
      console.log("successful!");
    } else if (changeInfo.url == "net.adjara.com/Movie/main*" || "net.adjara.come/Movie/*"){
        console.log("Movie page");
    } else {
        return false;
    }
  }
);
```

I added a console.log and it seems like it works on every page load, but it also seems like the code is still running on other sub-domains.

I want this code to run only on homepage. For others I will write another custom script, which will apply only to movie sub-domains.

I think I'm missing something important.

Comment: `||` doesn't work like that. You need to check the original variable against every value. Also URLs start with http:// or https://.

Comment: Okay, so I need to save the first url and compare it? What if I go to movie page right away?

Comment: Not what I meant. Example: var url = changeInfo.url; if (!url) { return } if (url === `'https://net.adjara.com/'` || url === `'https://net.adjara.com/Home'`) { ...... }

Comment: Doesn't work :/

Comment: Well of course you need to adapt it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're close. As [wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959875/woxxom) mentioned, your comparisons in your `if` statements don't quite have the right syntax. To format your multiple or's correctly, try:

```
if (changeInfo.url == "net.adjara.com" || 
    changeInfo.url == "net.adjara.com/Home" ||
    changeInfo.url == "net.adjara.com/Home/") {
    // your code block
  }
```

You can treat the `||` itself as the beginning of a new statement. We have to explicitly say which two things we are comparing for equality between each `||`. Using what I wrote above, you're asking your `if` statement to check for equality in each comparison separately. Then, if one or more of the those things are true, your code block will execute. (Bonus tip: If you have a series of `or` statements, if any one of them is true, the whole thing is true. Logic!)

Now, if you want to get fancy, you can accomplish this with regex. Here, you pass in your `changeInfo.url` string and check that the provided string starts with `net.adjara.com`.

```
if (changeInfo.url.match(/^net.adjara.com/) {
   // your code block
}
```

The set of `/` marks tell Javascript you are using regex, the `^` says you want to check the start of the string, and then you have your desired string that you want to match.

Of course, this might not work for your situation perfectly as I have it written. Your string may start with an "http://" or "https://" or whatever else. You can opt to use [a different regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) or perhaps you can look up [the `String.prototype.includes()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes). You know what your incoming strings look like better than I do!

Good luck!